# Why Is uint64 of NaN and MaxFloat64 equal in Golang?

Tags: go, floating-point, nan

The following condition evaluates to `true`, looking for an explanation as to why -

```
x, y := math.NaN(), math.MaxFloat64 

fmt.Println(uint64(x) == uint64(y))
```

`>>> true`

Specifically, why is `uint64(math.NaN())` = `9223372036854775808`?

Comment: See [Conversions Between Numeric Types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) in the spec.

Comment: This is not a feature of Go (note that this is the proper name of the language) but mandated by IEEE 754 floats in any language supporting them.

Comment: @Volker Does not IEEE 754 specify "NAN equal X" as _false_, for all X, even when X is also NAN?  The conversion of `NAN` and `MaxFloat64` to a `uint64` is certainly a language/implementation dependent issue and not a 754 one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It does but doubt that the bitpattern used for NaNs is a language/implementation dependent issue.

Comment: @Volker This really has nothing to do with the bit-pattern of NaN. Conversion to integer is handled by the hardware, and the corresponding instruction will specify what happens if the argument is NaN, or doesn't fit into the target.

Comment: @alias "Conversion to integer is handled by the hardware", no it doesn't.

Comment: @Volker Here's the assembly output: https://go.godbolt.org/z/YfqKdvY6E You can clearly see the call to  `cvttsd2si` on line 100.

Comment: @alias it depends on the architecture

Comment: @phuclv Of course. If the ISA doesn’t have support for these conversions that follow x86, then it’s purely implementation defined. I believe I made that clear in my answer. The OP is most likely using x86 or a variant thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language runtimes usually do not pay attention to what happens if you try to convert a `NaN` value to an integer. They typically simply issue the corresponding hardware instruction, and let the "hardware" do what it does.

So, the question is what does the hardware do in this case? Of course this depends on what your particular machine/ISA is. Assuming the most common Intel x86 architecture, the corresponding instruction used is most likely [CVTTSD2SI](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttsd2si), though you should check the assembly generated by your program to make sure this is indeed the case. Here's the relevant quote regarding this instruction's behavior:

> If a converted result exceeds the range limits of signed quadword integer (in 64-bit mode and REX.W/VEX.W/EVEX.W = 1), the floating-point invalid exception is raised, and if this exception is masked, the indefinite integer value (80000000_00000000H) is returned.

Based on this, what's happening is that the processor raises the invalid exception, which is masked by most language run-times by default, so your program simply keeps continuing. Consequently, you get the value `0x8000000000000000` as specified by the instruction, which is equivalent to `9223372036854775808` in decimal, explaining the result you observed.

If you worry about these conversions, you should either check for valid range before doing the conversion, or unmask the exception and let your program get a floating-point exception. Of course, you should carefully consider if it is worth doing the extra check as it will be a performance hit. Unmasking the exception, while morally the "correct" thing to do, is also problematic, as you wouldn't want your "number-crunching" program to crash at run-time. Obviously, the right thing to do depends on exactly what your circumstances/needs are.

### Note:

Here's the assembly output for your program on x86: https://go.godbolt.org/z/YfqKdvY6E You can see the call to `cvttsd2si` on line 100 and others. Here's a simpler program that compiles to a shorter assembly, whose output is easier to read, and showing the use of `cvtsd2si` more prominently on line 14: https://go.godbolt.org/z/r7Pq5Tqqh