# When I cast math.NaN() and math.MaxFloat64 to int, Why the result is different between go1.14.2 and go1.17.2?

Tags: go, casting, version

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    x, y := math.NaN(), math.MaxFloat64
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", int(x))
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", int(y))
}
```

That is my test code snippet. When I run the above code use go1.14.2, the result is

```
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
```

but the same code run in go1.17.2, the result is

```
0
9223372036854775807
```

I searched the simular question: [Why Is uint64 of NaN and MaxFloat64 equal in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70425809/why-is-uint64-of-nan-and-maxfloat64-equal-in-golang), which said that in the different hardware environment, the math.NaN() maybe different, but I run the code both in my MacOS M1 system, just golang version is different. Why the result is different between go1.14.2 and go1.17.2?

Comment: "I cast math.NaN() [...] to int". You cannot do this as there _are_ no casts in Go. And type conversions from constants (which behave differently than you probably are used to from other languages) have defined outcome only if sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spec: Conversions:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions)

> In all non-constant conversions involving floating-point or complex values, **if the result type cannot represent the value the conversion succeeds but the result value is implementation-dependent.**

You convert the floating-point value `NaN` to `int`. The valid values of the `int` type does not include the `NaN` value, so the value you convert cannot be represented by a value of type `int`, so the result is implementation-dependent. Basically, the spec allows it to be changed from version to version, from platform to platform. You cannot (should not) assume a specific `int` value for the conversion result.